# htaccess for multiple domains to wordpress subfolders

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I have an issue with dealing with multiple domains accesssing multiple wordpress installs on one server, each in its own subdomain.

- domain1
- domain2
- domain3

root
   folder1 (wp-install1)
   folder2 (wp-install2)
   folder3 (wp-install3)
   more folders

In the settings of my hoster, I can configure that

- domain1 points to /folder1
- domain2 points to /folder2
- domain3 points to /folder3

Of course, all domains should not display the folder.

How do I handle the .htaccess files?
I can't really show any code as I have been majorly unsuccessful.
I want to use permalinks in each wordpress install.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It is a little unclear what is the question, what is the problem that you have?

Comment: You need to add three separate htaccess files in folder 1,2 and 3